# Why does the embedded list not append 5

Tags: python, python-3.x

I visualized the steps on PythonTutor and saw that the variable c's counter keeps resetting after each iteration. I'm curious to know why this is so.  Also, how would I go about appending a value like 5 to each embedded list?

```
li=[[2,3],[3,4],[3,1]]
for i in li:
    c=0
    li[c].append(5)
    c+=1
```

what I get:

```
[[2, 3, 5, 5, 5], [3, 4], [3, 1]]
```

Comment: I'm not sure what is not clear here? The counter keep re-setting because on each iteration it's explicitly set to 0. To keep it running move the statement `c = 0` out of the for cycle, i.e. before the start of the cycle.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this but if all you want to do is append 5 to all the lists within the bigger list using what already exixst, then the only thing you need here is to declare c outside your for loop

```
li=[[2,3],[3,4],[3,1]]
c=0
for i in li:
    li[c].append(5)
    c+=1
```

Currently you are resetting the value of c to 0 and 1 every time you loop.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want.

```
li=[[2,3],[3,4],[3,1]]
for i in li:
    i.append(5)
print(li)
```

output:

```
[[2, 3, 5], [3, 4, 5], [3, 1, 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some extra unnecessary variable (`c` - As per my understanding it has to be list in your point of view i guess) and list appending also seems to be wrong.

Here is my try.

You can append to seperate list also if its necessary

**Code:**

```
li=[[2,3],[3,4],[3,1]]
for i in li:
    i.append(5)
    print (i)
```

**Output:**

```
[2, 3, 5]
[3, 4, 5]
[3, 1, 5]
```